# How to kill all application queries using server side Javascript in mongoDB ? 

Tags: mongodb

This is what I have tried, but does not seem to work, kills only 1 operation.

```
function s() {  
 t = db.currentOp()['inprog'];
 k= new Array(); 
 for(i=0;i< t.length;i++)
 { 
   if(t[i]["ns"].indexOf("my_namespace") != -1)  //fetch all required current Operations
             k.push(t[i]);
 }
 for(j=0;j<k.length;k++)
 {
   db.killOp(k[j]['opid']);   // kill them by opid , works only once
 }
```

Comment: What happens after you call killOp, does it return? Does it just die?

Comment: @gates, it returns, with proper status message like {'info' :'attempting to kil....}   , but kills only 1 operation, not all which are mentioned in the loop

Comment: @DhruvPathak - which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @DhruvPathak - then I think that JIRA in my answer is highly likely related - try upgrading and/or my suggested modification to your function.

Comment: @DhruvPathak - Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using v1.6, then the following JIRA is probably related to your problem, and was resolved in 1.7.2: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1816

So if this is the issue, try upgrading to 1.8. Or you could try the following:

```
for(each operation op identified in first loop)
{
  if(op still exists) { // op could have finished
     kill op;
     while(op still there) // May not be possible to kill op 
     {                     // if another is being killed
       wait 1 sec;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(j=0;j<k.length;k++)
 {
   db.killOp(k[j]['opid']);   // kill them by opid , works only once
 }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't this be... (j++ not k++ because you are just infinitely increasing the length of k). Hence j will only ever = 0 and only ever kill the first value in k.

```
 for(j=0;j<k.length;j++)
 {
   db.killOp(k[j]['opid']);   // kill them by opid , works only once
 }
```

Comment: thts a typo.even with correct code,it kills the first op only.